# Buy tickets for Vatican museum online?

Tags: italy, rome, vatican-city

As the title may give you a hint, I'll be in a Rome for the first time.

The challenge now - is there a website where I can buy tickets (with a guide included) for Vatican museums?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Vatican [Online Ticket Office](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do) and every imaginable tour, spoiled for choice:

> **[VATICAN BY TRAIN](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=40&step=1):**
>   New!
>   For individuals who desire a tour of the Vatican Museums, the Sistine Chapel, the Vatican Gardens and the Pontifical Residence in Castel Gandolfo by train.
>
> **[NIGHT OPENINGS 2017](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=17&step=1):**
>   An extraordinary opportunity to visit the Vatican Museums after sunset. Opening from 7pm to 11pm
>
> **[ADMISSION TICKETS](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=9&step=1):**
>   For visitors who would like to reserve the admission ticket of the Vatican Museums and Sistine Chapel online skipping the line.
>
> **[GUIDED TOURS FOR INDIVIDUALS](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=4&step=1):**
>   For individuals who want to join a guided group tour to the Vatican Museums, to the Necropolis of the Via Triumphalis, to the Vatican Gardens on foot or by Open Bus.
>
> **[GUIDED TOURS WITH EXCLUSIVE GUIDE](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=13&step=1):**
>   For groups (up to 15 people) who desire a guided tour to the Vatican Museums or to the Vatican Gardens.
>
> **[BREAKFAST AT THE MUSEUMS](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=34&step=1):**
>   Breakfast and admission to the Vatican Museums and Sistine Chapel.
>
> **[PONTIFICAL RESIDENCE OF CASTEL GANDOLFO](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=33&step=1):**
>   For visitors who desire to visit the Barberini Gardens inside the Pontifical Villas or the Museum of the Apostolic Palace in Castel Gandolfo.
>
> **[PILGRIMAGES](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=5&step=1):**
>   For Parishes and Religious Institutions who desire a visit to the Vatican Museums or to the Vatican Gardens.
>
> **[GUIDED TOURS FOR GROUPS](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=12&step=1):**
>   For groups (more than 16 people) who desire a guided tour to the Vatican Museums, to the Vatican Gardens or to the Necropolis of the Via Triumphalis.
>
> **[HIDDEN VATICAN MUSEUMS](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=29&step=1):**
>   For groups (up to 20 people) who desire a guided tour of special areas of the Vatican Museums.
>
> **[VATICAN MUSEUMS AFTER HOURS](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=31&step=1):**
>   For groups who desire an exclusive tour of less well known areas of the Vatican Museums outside normal opening times.
>
> **[EDUCATIONAL TOURS](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=6&step=1)**:
>   For Primary and High Schools who desire a visit to the Vatican Museums or to the Vatican Gardens.
>
> **[EDUCATIONAL TOURS AND DIDACTIC LABORATORY](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=22&step=1)**:
>   This kind of visit is not available in English.
>
> **[UNIVERSITY GROUPS](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=20&step=1):**
>   For Universities who desire a visit to the Vatican Museums or to the Vatican Gardens.
>
> **[ANIMATED EDUCATIONAL TOURS](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=23&step=1):**
>   This kind of visit is not available in English.
>
> **[EXCAVATIONS OF ST. JOHN LATERAN](https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=10&step=1):**
>   For Groups who desire to visit the Archaeological Area of St. John Lateran.

Answer (score 3):

(what a wonderful tool that is google)

Yes.

General admission: 
https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=9&step=1

Guided Tours for Individuals: 
https://biglietteriamusei.vatican.va/musei/tickets/do?action=booking&codiceLivelloVisita=4&step=1