# Is it worth pre-booking for Vatican Museums etc.?

Tags: tips-and-tricks, rome, pre-pay, vatican-city

I've seen a link suggesting that [I might want to pre-book a fast track](https://www.tripadvisor.com/AttractionProductDetail-g187793-d631111-a_aidSuffix.crmibpostbook-a_product.3731VATICAN-St_Peter_s_Basilica-Vatican_City_Lazio.html) to some of the attractions connected to the Vatican City.

I'm not sure if it's just a way to lock me into paying for something that is equally easy/cheap to do while on-site.

Comment: When I was at the Vatican in 2015, the lines were long as a mile. **Might** be worth paying for quick access.

Comment: @Phantom How was the cost? Do you remember?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89895/buy-tickets-for-vatican-museum-online

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. Your link seems to have overwhelmingly positive reviews from over 20,000 people. It must be genuine and recommended. I wouldn't hesitate.